# retrieving the value between tags XML Xerces C++ Parser

Tags: c++, c, xml, xerces

I'm currently using Xerces library to parse a XML file in C++. I have the algorithm parser written, and the only thing missing is how to retrieve the value between two tags?
For example,
`<name>John</name>`, I would like to be able to get the value John, so I could store in a string variable which I have for that purpose. I know that using

```
DOMElement * current = root->getFirstChildElement();
const XMLCh * tag = current->getTagName();
cout << XMLString::transcode(tag) << endl;
```

I will be able to print that tag, but I'm more interested in the value between tags. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at the Xerces documentation?

Answer (score 5):

`DOMNode::getTextContent()` will give you **John** from your example

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `current->getNodeValue()` ?

Comment: It will probably give you an empty result if the node has elements as content.  You will probably see non-empty results for nodes that have mixed or text content.  In your example, you are using the first child of the root node.  Does that node have mixed content?